# Не открываются файлы .jar

Tags: java, jar

Есть исполняемый файл, одно время открывался. Но что-то произошло и он перестал открываться, а только начинает распаковку. Если делать через терминал то все запускается. В чем проблема?
Все на Mac

Comment: видимо поменялась стандартная программа для запуска файлов с таким типом, возможно вы установили новый архиватор

Comment: Возможно... Но как мне найти то, через что я могу запустить файлы такого типа, и поменять способ открытия по умолчанию?